# DaisyChain from GeForce GTX 860M HDMI output

Tags: multiple-monitors, daisychaining

I have a laptop with GeForce GTX 860M, which has an HDMI output. The laptop connects to a DELL screen HDMI in, and the DELL screen DisplayPort out is connected to another screen's DP in. Should that work? Currently I'm trying to set it up without success

Comment: Does your Dell screen support HDMI-in to DP-out? It seems in this case that the weak link here is the screen's capabilities. Typically an HDMI splitter or something similar would be used when attempting to output to multiple screens like this.

Comment: Well, not sure what is the answer to your question. The monitor used is Dell U2415. It has HDMI-in, DP-in and DP-out but my laptop only has HDMI-out.
Is HDMI splitter the only option or is there a chance I can get the current setup to work?

Comment: According to http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/SLN295251/EN - Attempting to daisy chain like this is only supported by DisplayPort. So the HDMI could not be daisy-chained to the DP-out. You would need DP-out from your PC to the monitor's DP-in, then DP-out from the monitor to DP-in on the second monitor. However I am not experienced enough with DP specifically to post this as a definitive answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should that work?

No.

To daisy chain with display port you need a display port 1.2 source. That source then provides the output for both daisy chained displays. The first display shows its part of the stream. The second monitor is daisy chained from the first monitors DP out but the source of the data is still your desktops DP 1.2 plug.

If you use a HDMI output then you get HDMI out. You can convert that for a single DP monitor, but you do not have multiple DP streams on a HDMI output.

The other way around is theoretically possible (DP out to a DP monitor, then chained from that to a second screen via DP to HDMI), but then you need a very smart DP 1.2. to HDMI convertor. Which might be more expensive than a new monitor or a new graphics card.

Comment: DisplayPort is very picky, seemingly on both ends, graphics card and monitor.  Sometimes an active converter helps but it all depends.  I've had to go through 3 monitors on one station to get a DP out to work consistently.

Comment: I only have one DP port capable monitor. It worked with both my old (AMD 5780 card) and my new (GTX960) card. Those situation just worked. Maybe I was lucky. Maybe you had bad luck. Future will tell.